# tensorflow ctc_loss how to understand labels param

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow document:
labels.values[i] must take on values in [0, num_labels], allow values[i] have zero value,

labels is SparseTensor,
indices: specifies the indices of the elements in the sparse tensor that contain nonzero values, values:which supplies the values for each element in indices

according to sparsetensor define, labels.values[i] is nonzero value, but tf.nn.ctc_loss labels.values allow labels.values[i] have zero value,

how to understand labels.values[i] allow have zero value

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: tf.nn.ctc_loss the first param labels, tensorflow document says value must be in [0,num_labels), but for label is a sparse tensor, almost everywhere is 0 excepted for some specified places , for example, some character image samples, label is  A~Z,   labels values is[0, 26),
 but image samples is Variable-Length, for example the first image is 'afg', the second image is 'acatnap', how to input labels  to tf.nn.ctc_loss

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question